# Error with List<String> in Java

Tags: java, string, list

I have a program to create a String to build a table,it works alright until I need to "leave the loop" (when the allClear should be true) but it keeps returning false.

I tried printing the String ret and it always got a String like "   |    |   ". Since that happens, it means that the List l has all the Strings set to "", and in that case the method allClear should return true.

This is the code for the method to build the columns for the table, it gets the List with all the Strings and how many columns the table should have, then returns the String with all the table Strings.

It should return a String like: "Col 1  | Col 2  | Col 3\nCol 1  | Col 2  | Col 3",

```
public static String buildNCol(List<String> l, int n)throws NotEnoughStringsException{
    if(l.size()<n)throw new NotEnoughStringsException("Not enough Strings given");
    int colSize = colSize(n);
    int colN,curChar,curSize;
    String ret="",temp="";
    boolean check = true;
    while(check){
        ret="";
        for(colN=0;colN<n;colN++){
            temp = getLine(l,colN,colSize);
            for(curSize=temp.length();curSize<colSize;curSize++)temp+=' ';
            if(colN!=n-1)temp+=" | ";
            ret+=temp;
        }
        ret+='\n';
        for(colN=0;colN<n;colN++)l.set(colN,cutString(l.get(colN)));
        if(allClear(l,n))check=true; //This is where the error happens
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This is the allClear method. This method checks if all the n first strings in the list are all set to "", null or "\n".

```
private static boolean allClear(List<String> l,int n){
    int i;
    String temp;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        temp = l.get(i);
        if(temp!=null&&temp.length()>1) return false;
        if(temp.length()==1&&temp.charAt(0)!='\n')return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `check` is initially set to `true`, conditionally set to `true` when `allClear` returns `true`.  Nothing inside the `while` loop ever sets `check` to `false` or issues a `break`, so **it's gonna loop forever**.

Comment: Now seems like a good time to figure out [how to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @KevinAnderson I can't believe that was the error, you saved me a LOT of time here, THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as said in the comments by Kevin Anderson, 
check is initially set to true, conditionally set to true when allClear returns true. Nothing inside the while loop ever sets check to false or issues a break, so it's gonna loop forever.

You can fix this by setting check to false like so:

```
check = false;
```

Comment: The method returning there is not a problem. The method is called "**all**Clear" - if *one* is not clear, it should return false - the rest don't matter, so it can return right away. Best practices aside...

Answer (score 0):

As @KevinAnderson said in the comment, the error in the program was that check never gets to false, since I coded it to "change" to true instead of false